# Rendering Huge Dataset from API to Table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I make a GET to an API, then I got 1000 accounts.

[image]

Then, I'm using [datatable](https://datatables.net/) to rendering my table like this.

[image]

---

The performance seem a bit slow, and I'm trying to improve it. 
I did some research and I found [this](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side), but I don't have access to the database, but I have access to API that return those 1000 accounts as an array.

---

I'm certainly open to all feedback and suggestions about this process.

---

Here is my datatable settings

```
var account_table =  $('#account-table').DataTable({
  "bPaginate": true,
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
  "deferLoading": 10,

});
```

For "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php", since I am using API, can I just do

"ajax": "https://jsonblob.com/57c08bb2e4b0dc55a4f0eec7" ????

Here is all my sample data : https://jsonblob.com/57c08bb2e4b0dc55a4f0eec7

Comment: is https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading an option?

Comment: What is the length (bytes) of these 1000 records? How much time does it take to do the request to the server?

Comment: @Dekel : As of now, the request took less than 1 second to return to 1000 accounts objects.

Comment: @saj : I tried it, and it doesn't seem to work. Have you ever make it work ? Have you ever deal with this before ? Any further suggestions will be great ?

Comment: @ihue, how much time does it take when you go with 10 records? or 100? or 500? Many instead of fetch all 1000 you should fetch only the first 2-5 pages, and when someone go to page 4 just lazyfetch pages 6-10.

Comment: @Dekel : I am new to all of these. Do you have any suggestions on how to do what you said ? It sounds interesting, I would like to learn more.

Comment: @ihue I've not used that, at work we use DOJO ( I know it's old) but has some great grids including DGRIDS on demand grid, it essentialy gets a page at a time and you can accomodate gazzillions of rows.http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/grids_and_stores/demo/OnDemandGrid-comparison.html or http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/stxZc/

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely the slowest part about this process is getting those accounts over the web.

Instead of requesting them each time, you could cache them and only request them once every `x` amount of time.

*pseudo code*

```
function getAccounts() {
    if (!cache.has("accounts")) {
        // supposedly cache data for 1 hour
        cache.set("accounts", getAccountsFromAPI(), 3600);
    }

    return cache.get("accounts");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Although **Caching** looks like the good fit in this situation, but what if the users create/update an account, then, I will lead to ourdated accounts info. How do I deal with that ? any further suggestion regarding caching ?